# Fitting hyperbolic functions ($\tanh$) on data.

Tags: approximation, hyperbolic-functions

Suppose i have some data dependant on 2 variables n and T. If i plot this data choosing n= 5 and letting T vary from 1 to 100 i get the following curve:

[image]

Where the blue curve is my real data and the yellow curve is the function $FIT(n,T) = \tanh(\frac{T^{-2} n}{\log(4)})$. Is there a way to move my tangent line in the interval $1,10$ with some continuous deformation such that my function $FIT(n,T)$ fits the data? Furthermore does anyone have suggestions of other functions that may fit. The green line added is the function $G(5,T) = \frac{T^{-2}*5}{\log(4)} $

[image]

For the interested: The function i try to fit is of the form: 
$$
F(\beta,n) = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \left(\frac{e^{\beta}}{e^{\beta} + e^{-\beta}}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{e^{-\beta}}{e^{\beta} + e^{-\beta}}\right)^{n-k} \log_{2}(1+\left(e^{2\beta}\right)^{n-2k}) 
$$
Where $\beta = \frac{1}{T}$. Note tat the above plots are on logarithmic scale, the usual plots look different. For example if n = 100: You can clearly see its convergence to some powerlaw function which is the green line:

[image]

Here is also the slope of the loglogplot that we see of the function F(n,T):
[image]

Comment: Can you please double check the expression you post for $F$ is the right one? I tried to plot it and got something very different. Thanks

Comment: the logarithm is the second logarithm so Log_{2},

This is what i filled in mathematica:

q[a_, B_] := E^(a*B)/(E^(a*B) + E^(-a*B))

F[n_, B_] = 
 1 - Sum[Binomial[n, k]*q[1, B]^k (1 - q[1, B])^(n - k)
     Log[2, 1 + E^(2 B (n - 2 k))], {k, 0, n}]

Comment: Note that i got a logarithmic scale as well, i will add the normal scaled functions right now

Comment: The fact that is base-2 logarithm actually makes a difference, maybe you should add that to the post $\color{red}{\log_2}(\cdots)$

Answer (score 2):

You know a couple of things

- At low $T$ the function behaves as a constant $F \sim 1$
- At a given temperature $T \sim T_0$ the function changes behavior
- For $T \gg T_0$ the function decays nearly as $F \sim T^{-2}$

A trial function that follows this constraints is

$$
F(T) = \frac{F_0}{[1 + (T/T_0)^\gamma]^{2/\gamma}}
$$

These are some results for $n = 5$

\begin{eqnarray}
F_0 &=& 1.00628391 \\
T_0 &=&1.74144763 \\
\gamma &=& 3.2810511 
\end{eqnarray}

which results in

[image]

Comment: I do understand that for low T you function F(T) goes to F_0, and i see that the term in the denominator converges to $T^{-2}$ for big $T$. However is there an ideal way to choose $\gamma$, $F_0$ and $T_0$? I see you have specific floats so i just assumed you used some optimiatization algorithm?

Comment: @KeesTil yes, I just fitted my model to your function and found these values

Comment: Nice, however this will probably not work if we try to fit in the $n$ dimension as well. I see that $F(T,n) \sim n$ for big $n$, so maybe adding up that information i can try finding a 2-dimensional fit.

Comment: @KeesTil Effectively all parameters depend on $n$: $f_0 = f_0(n)$, $\gamma = \gamma(n)$ and $T_0 = T_0(n)$